# A problem with image paths and URLs in Android Java app

Tags: java, android, url

I am making a gardening app using Java and SQLite. I create a database with 8 vegetables in my MainActivity:

```
VegetableEntry tomato = new VegetableEntry(-1, "Tomato", "medium", "summer", "loamy", "60 kcal per 100g", "tomato", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato");

            VegetableEntry potato = new VegetableEntry(-1, "Potato", "medium", "autumn", "sandy", "60 kcal per 100g", "potato", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato");
            VegetableEntry cabbage = new VegetableEntry(-1, "Cabbage", "medium", "autumn", "clay", "60 kcal per 100g", "cabbage", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabbage");
            VegetableEntry cucumber = new VegetableEntry(-1, "Cucumber", "medium", "summer", "loamy", "60 kcal per 100g", "cucumber", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucumber");
            VegetableEntry onion = new VegetableEntry(-1, "Onion", "medium", "autumn", "silty", "60 kcal per 100g", "onion", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onion");
            VegetableEntry eggplant = new VegetableEntry(-1, "Eggplant", "medium", "summer", "sandy", "60 kcal per 100g", "eggplant", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggplant");
            VegetableEntry carrot = new VegetableEntry(-1, "Carrot", "medium", "spring", "sandy", "60 kcal per 100g", "carrot", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrot");
            VegetableEntry turnip = new VegetableEntry(-1, "Turnip", "medium", "winter", "sandy", "60 kcal per 100g", "turnip", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnip");

            // Print the URLs for debugging
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Tomato URL: " + tomato.getArticleURL());
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Potato URL: " + potato.getArticleURL());
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Cabbage URL: " + cabbage.getArticleURL());
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Cucumber URL: " + cucumber.getArticleURL());
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Onion URL: " + onion.getArticleURL());
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Eggplant URL: " + eggplant.getArticleURL());
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Carrot URL: " + carrot.getArticleURL());
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Turnip URL: " + turnip.getArticleURL());

            DataBaseHelper.add_One(tomato);
            DataBaseHelper.add_One(potato);
            DataBaseHelper.add_One(cabbage);
            DataBaseHelper.add_One(cucumber);
            DataBaseHelper.add_One(onion);
            DataBaseHelper.add_One(eggplant);
            DataBaseHelper.add_One(carrot);
            DataBaseHelper.add_One(turnip);
```

Then in another activity I have a listView and I populate it with the vegetables. Each vegetable item displays a picture and URL. However, instead of getting "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato" on the screen, for example, I get just a "tomato". This "tomato" is the path I use to include the image for the tomato vegetable entry.
And my VegetableEntry code seems okay so I don't know what the issue is:

```
package de.thu.appgardening;

public class VegetableEntry {


    private int id;
    private String sort;
    private String effort;
    private String season;
    private String soil;
    private String nutriValue;
    private String imagePath;
    private String articleURL;



    VegetableEntry() {};

    VegetableEntry( int id, String sort, String effort, String season, String soil, String nutriValue, String imagePath, String articleURL){

        this.id = id;
        this.sort = sort;
        this.effort = effort;
        this.season = season;
        this.soil = soil;
        this.nutriValue = nutriValue;
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
        this.articleURL = articleURL;
    }

    //getters

    int getId() { return this.id; }

    String getSort(){
        return this.sort;
    }

    String getEffort(){
        return this.effort;
    }

    String getSeason(){
        return this.season;
    }

    String getSoil(){
        return this.soil;
    }

    String getNutriValue(){
        return this.nutriValue;
    }

    String getImagePath() {return this.imagePath; }

    String getArticleURL() {return this.articleURL; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " " +
                "id=" + id +
                ", sort='" + sort + '\'' +
                ", effort=" + effort +
                ", season=" + season +
                ", soil= " + soil +
                ", calories " + nutriValue +
                ", image_path = " + imagePath +
                ", URL = " + articleURL + ' ';
    }
}
```

This is the activity where I'm trying to access the URLs:

```
public class Effort extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_effort);

            listView = findViewById(R.id.list);

            DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(Effort.this);

            // Get a list of vegetables from the database
            List<VegetableEntry> vegetables = dataBaseHelper.getAllVegetables();

            // Create and set the ArrayAdapter
            ArrayAdapter<VegetableEntry> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<VegetableEntry>(this, R.layout.list_item_layout, R.id.itemTextView, vegetables) {
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View listItemView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                    // Find the ImageView and TextView in the inflated layout
                    ImageView imageView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.itemImageView);
                    TextView textView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTextView);

                    // Use the VegetableEntry at the current position
                    VegetableEntry vegetable = getItem(position);

                    // Use getters from VegetableEntry to retrieve sort and effort values
                    String sort = vegetable.getSort();
                    String effort = vegetable.getEffort();
                    String imageName = vegetable.getImagePath(); // Assuming imageName is the resource name without extension
                    Uri vegetableArticleURL = Uri.parse(vegetable.getArticleURL());

                    // Load the image from the drawable resource
                    int imageResId = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", getPackageName());
                    if (imageResId != 0) {
                        imageView.setImageResource(imageResId);
                    } else {
                        // Handle the case where the resource is not found
                        // You can set a default image or show an error
                    }

                    // Set the text for the TextView
                    String displayText = "Sort: " + sort + "\nEffort: " + effort + "\nURL: " + vegetableArticleURL.toString();
                    textView.setText(displayText);

                    return listItemView;
                }
            };

            listView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
                VegetableEntry selectedVegetable = (VegetableEntry) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Log information
                Log.d("ItemClick", "Selected Vegetable: " + selectedVegetable);

                if (selectedVegetable != null && selectedVegetable.getArticleURL() != null) {
                    openWikipediaArticle(selectedVegetable);
                } else {
                    // Log or handle the case where selectedVegetable or its URL is null
                    Log.e("ItemClick", "Invalid Vegetable or URL is null");
                }
            });
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);



        }

    public void openWikipediaArticle(VegetableEntry vegetable) {

            String url = vegetable.getArticleURL();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
            Log.d("Effort", "Opening Wikipedia article with URL: " + url);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            // Handle the case where the URL is empty
            Log.e("Effort", "Invalid URL: " + url);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid URL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The code you posted here should 'work', i.e. `articleURL` should always have the full link to the article. The order of the parameters in the `VegetableEntry` constructor match the order you set them in in your `MainActivity`. I suspect however that the problem is not so much in how you are *saving* your data, but how you are *loading* your data. Can you add that code to your question, and also add the relevant code for the listview where the problem occurs?